# PowerApps: Send an email with values of dynamic collection

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-portal

I have built a Power Apps, with a SharePoint list as data source. The list consist of 4 columns (static,  number will be always the same) and several rows (dynamic - items can be added deleted). See below and attached attached

**Title**         / **Description**        / **Signature**        / **Kind**
Item 1 Title / Item 1 Description / Item 1 Signature / Item 1 Kind
Item 2 Title / Item 2 Description / Item 2 Signature / Item 2 Kind

The purpose is to send an email with values, which are selected in PowerApps.

I have a list, which is viewed in the app as Gallery List and shows only the Titles and Kinds of items. Each item in the app has a check box, which is used for collecting it on "Check" action using Collect function:

`Collect(Collection2,ThisItem)`

The collection is then previewed in another Gallery List (meant to be not visible), which shows the column values, that I want to send in the email message: values of checked items from "Title, Description,  Signature" columns. For the email I use below. "Title3", "Subtitle2" and "Body1" are field identifiers from the Gallery.

```
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(TextInput3,"GCP Agreement Cover letter", Concat(Collection1,
"<b>" & "Agreement title" & "</b>" & "<br>" &
"&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Title3 & "<br>" &
"<b>" & "Agreement Description" & "</b>" & "<br>" &
"&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Subtitle2 & "<br>" &
"<b>" & "Signed by" & "</b>" & "<br>" &
"&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Body1 & "<br>" & "<br>"& "<br>" & "<br>"))
```

The problem is, that the email does not contain dynamic values, which are checked, but static: the first checked value is replicated to the amount "checked" items (luckily that works).  For example, if the first two items are checked:

As is:

**Agreement title**
Item 1 Title
**Agreement Description**
Item 1 Description
**Signed by**
Item 1 Signature

**Agreement title**
Item 1 Title
**Agreement Description**
Item 1 Description
**Signed by**
Item 1 Signature

To be

**Agreement title**
Item 1 Title
**Agreement Description**
Item 1 Description
**Signed by**
Item 1 Signature

**Agreement title**
Item 2 Title
**Agreement Description**
Item 2 Description
**Signed by**
Item 2 Signature

Can anybody help with having correct values in the email message?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to filter by checkbox, you can use the Filter() function to select items that just have the checkbox checked. And then Concat() to merge the remaining items into a string.

```
Concat(Filter(Gallery3.AllItems, ThisRecord.Checkbox1.Value),ThisRecord.SampleText)
```